# How to check if a type is a typedef of int

Tags: c++, constructor, c-preprocessor, typedef

In C++, I want to have a class whose constructors are the following:

```
class A {
  explicit A(A* other) { ... }
  explicit A(intptr_t other) { ... }
};
```

The problem with this is if the user initialize with

```
A a(0);
```

Then, on a 64 bits system, the compiler will complain that it doesn't know if `0` should be converted to `A*` or to `intptr_t`, which is fair enough. As I want this simple notation to work, I added the following constructor:

```
explicit A(int a) { assert(a==0); ... }
```

The assertion is because this is the only integer this makes sense for. Now, the problem arises with a 32 bits system, in which `intptr_t` is actually ... `int` ! So now, the system complains there are two constructors taking the same parameter type (which, again, is fair enough).

So my question is: is there a way with the preprocessor to detect that `intptr_t` is actually `int` and, in that case, not compile the constructor with `int`. Or, is there another way to make the `A a(0)` notation valid without adding the constructor with `int`, but without removing either of the two first constructor (and not making them implicit either).

Comment: Could you not remove the A(A* other) constructor and replace with A(A& other). It would seem more natural to me (assume you are copying other and not chaining).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
#if INTPTR_MAX == INT_MAX
```

might do the trick, but it will still result in true where `long` and
`int` are the same size, and `ptrint_t` is a typedef for `long`.
Another possibility (but don't know whether you can use it or not)
would be to use `uintptr_t`, rather than `intptr_t`.

Beyond these: the preprocessor doesn't know about types, so the problem 
can't be solved there.  You'll have to use some sort of meta-programming
trick: you make the `int` constructor a template, using
`boost::enable_if` to activate it only if the argument has type `int`.
If `ptrint_t` is `int`, then the activated function will never be
used, because it will never be a better match than the non-template
function with the same signature.  If `ptrint_t` isn't `int`, then the
template instantiation will be a better match when the argument has type
`int`.  (Note that I've never tried this myself: it sounds to me like it
should be possible, but I'm not that familiar with `boost::enable_if` to
be sure.)

Comment: @PierreBdR The simplest solutions are the best:-)!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simple implemment a parameterless constructor that acts as if `other` were `0`? If, for some reason you don't want to, I suggest using type traits, provided you have access to C++11 compiler or boost:

```
class A { 
public:
    explicit A(A* other) { ... } 
    explicit A(intptr_t other) { ... } 

    template <class T>
    explicit A(T other)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible<T, intptr_t>::value, "Could not convert value to intptr_t");
        static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "Argument must be integral");
        intptr_t p = other;
        ...
    }
};
```

You can get rid of static assertions and type checkings, but then instead of compiler error you would get a warning (depending on your warning level, may even be turned into an error) when you do the following:

```
A a(0.0f);
```

Comment: It's possible, but has two downside: it's complicated, any use of the constructor with a wrong type will give a non-obvious error.

Comment: @PierreBdR What exactly do you find complicated here? Static assertions are self-explainatory. Same for error messages generated by them. Is "Argument must be integral" really non-obvious?

Comment: It's more a problem of using a template function to solve a problem not linked to templates in the first place. Anyway, as you may see, my favoured solution has been to change from `intptr_t` to `uintptr_t`, which is, you will admit, simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the simplest thing is to declare all 6 constructors (int, long, long long, and their unsigned variants), instead of using intptr_t.

Comment: Then why not to have still simpler `template` solution ?

Comment: This is a simple and effective solution to the problem you stated

Comment: Simple indeed, but requires to define all constructors ... and I still don't know which one correspond to `intptr_t`. As you can imagine, I use `intptr_t` to hold ... a pointer as a number. So I really can't "use" any of the other definition, or I would have to start asking about the size of the types.

Comment: @Rierre the million dollar question is do you *need* to know what integer type corresponds to `intptr_t`? Why do you need to know?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb as I said, the `intptr_t` is holding an actual pointer. So calling the constructor with anything but this specific type has no meaning, unless the value is 0!

Answer (score -1):

> is there another way to make the `A a(0)` notation valid

Just introduce a `template` constructor.

```
class A {
public:
  template<typename T>
  explicit  A (T t) { assert(t==0); }  // explicit matters ?

  explicit A(A* other) { ... }
  explicit A(intptr_t other) { ... }
};
```

This will solve your 32-bit and 64-bit problem!

Comment: And how does that solve the problem? Access error instead of ambiguity error?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr, I was modifying the post. See the updated answer. I thought OP wanted to restrict `0`. However in question it's mentioned as `assert()`, which means the other way. I corrected it.

Answer (score -1):

You can also pass a parameter, which determines which one is called :

```
struct TakePtr{};
struct TakeInt{};

class A {
  A(A* other, const TakePtr&) { ... }
  A(intptr_t other, const TakeInt&) { ... }
};
```

This way you can make sure which constructor is called :

```
A a2( 0, TakeInt() );     // calls the 2nd constructor, taking int
A a1( &a2, TakePtr() );   // calls the 1st constructor, taking a pointer
```

Comment: This is not a good way of accomplishing the task. It introduces unnecessary [readability code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell#Common_code_smells). It can be done in simpler way.

Comment: @iammilind So, which one exactly item from that list is the above code breaking? Or is it more items? The code above is going to prevent any conversion, and is using the specific constructor to create an object.

Comment: `Or is it more items`; yes, that is unnecessary. Your code will accomplish the task, but at the same time, the coder needs to be disciplined about passing the appropriate type; thus looses its abstraction. Also, this kind of bug can go unnoticed silently: `A a2(0, TakePtr()); // oops it should be TakeInt()`

Comment: @iammilind Off course. All developers should be disciplined, otherwise they can produce even mode stupid code then what you wrote in the comment above :) That is what unit tests (and other tests) are for.

Comment: @VJovic Yes, but you require programmers to take extra measures that are inadequate to the weight of the problem. These kind of requirements are *extremely* frustrating to work with.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr So, the problem is in the class that has two constructors where the parameter can be converted to one or the other type expected by constructors?

Comment: @VJovic Uhm, yes? Problems like that feel like a minor language issue. If your solution to a minor language issue is to force co-programmers to use unnatural and unidiomatic concepts each damn time, they will hate you with their very guts.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr *a minot language issue* is the cause of the problem in the question ;) This solution explicitly tells which constructor to use.